# 2-edge connectivity with edge perturbations

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random, random-graphs

Consider a graph $G$, and inside this graph consider two vertices $i$ and $j$ that are connected to each other, through an intermediate node $v$: 
$$
... i - v - j   ...
$$

We make some local modifications to this graph. 
Suppose we duplicate $v$, $k$-times and create a cluster of nodes $V$. Each node in this cluster is connected to $i$ with probability $p$ (independent of each other); similarly, each node can be connected to $j$ with probability $q$. With this probability of having a path between $i$ and $j$ is $1 - (1-pq)^k$.

Suppose we randomly with prob. $r$ add edges between any node-pairs in $V$.  What would be the probability of having a connection between $i$ and $j$?

Comment: Would it help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326804/probability-of-two-vertices-to-be-connected-in-gn-p

Comment: Yes, thanks. I will complete your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is called 2-terminal reliability problem (thanks to @Salomo for pointing it out). To the extent that I searched there is no analytical closed form.

An easier solution is to use [the phase transition results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G(n,_p)). For example, if $r > \frac{\log n}{n}$ $V$ will almost surely be connected, which means that the probability of having a path is $1-(1-p)^k(1-q)^k$ and (almost surely) independent of the exact value of $r$.